# Installing an old Nvidia driver

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I wanted to switch my desktop computer over to Ubuntu, but I have had issues with Nouveau (messed up desktop backgrounds, apps downright unusable), probably because I'm using a Nvidia GeForce 7300 LE. I tried manually installing the newest driver that supports my card (304.137) through the .run installer, but it just gives in an error saying that it was unable to build the Nvidia kernel module. Looking through the log file, it says that nvidia.ko failed to build right before the installation failed. I am using Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.4 LTS, though I have had the exact same issues on every Ubuntu distro and desktop I've tried.

Comment: Forget about proprietary drivers for this device on new Ubuntu releases. `nouveau` should work well enough.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: The latest Ubuntu release where the 304 driver can be used is 16.04.

Comment: And what are the "issues"?

Comment: I specified the issues. For one thing, the backgrounds are always messed up. TThis session it decided to go with a searing yellow on one display and what looks like TV static on the other, with the actual background slightly visible behind those. The other main issue is that some apps just are downright unusable due to the visual glitches.

Comment: The graphics driver ppa has 3.04 for 18.04, whether it works, no idea,  https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: It says that the packages "xorg-video-abi-[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, or 20]" are not installable.